# using the store function in a link_to_action in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Hi i am trying to use the store function by passing parameters to it using the link_to_action but whenever i do it just seems to go to the index (and proceed to display nothing as my index function is empty for this controller.

```
{{ link_to_action('ApplicationController@store', 'Apply', $ids = array(Auth::user()->id => 'user_id',$job->id=>'job_id'))
```

is the link_to_Action i am using am i just missing something or is there something else i need to add i know it is going to the index function because if i place something in there it will follow through with that

edit:
route decleration

```
Route::get('job/allJobs', array('as' => 'job.allJobs', 'uses' => 

'JobController@allJobs'));
Route::post('job/search', array('as' => 'job.search', 'uses' => 'JobController@search'));
Route::get('job/searchForm', array('as' => 'job.searchForm', 'uses' => 'JobController@searchForm'));
Route::get('user/allUsers', array('as' => 'user.allUsers', 'uses' => 'UserController@allUsers'));
Route::post('user/login', array('as' => 'user.login', 'uses' => 'UserController@login'));
Route::get('user/logout', array('as' => 'user.logout', 'uses' => 'UserController@logout'));
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('job', 'JobController');
Route::resource('application', 'ApplicationController');
```

controller decleration

```
public function store()
{
    $ids = Ids::all();
$application = new Application;
$application->user_id = $ids->user_id;
$application->job_id = $ids->job_id;
$application->save();
return Redirect::route('user.index');
}
```

Edit 2: so as i failed to figure out why it wasnt working i have used a roundabout way to achieve the same result creating a form with hidden elements and using the default value to populate them with the correct data like so:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'application.store')) }}
        {{Form::hidden('user_id',Auth::user()->id)}}
        {{Form::hidden('job_id',$job->id)}}
        {{Form::submit('Apply')}}
        {{Form::close()}}
```

which works as i wanted thankyou for the suggestion though werewolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this (Assumed it's not a `resourceful controller` and `$job` is within the scope):

```
{{ link_to_action(
        'ApplicationController@store',
        'Apply',
        array('user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'job_id' => $job->id)
    )
}}
```

**Update:** You have a `resourceful controller` here;

```
Route::resource('application', 'ApplicationController');
```

So, you can't just use a `GET` request to invoke the `store` method. You need to submit a `POST` request using a `FORM` ( Also possible using `AJAX`). The `URI` should be:

```
// Use method = 'POST'
http://yourdomain/application
```

So, generate a `form` and pass the parameters using form field, for example:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'application', 'method' => 'post')) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::user()->id) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('job_id', $job->id) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Apply') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

If you submit this form then the `store` method will be invoked. For more, check [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) on `Laravel` website.

Comment: this is still going to my index function as opposed to my store :(

Comment: Show your `controller` and `route` declaration.